# Can an element's CSS class be set via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to do this:

```
e.className = t;
```

Where t is the name of a style I have defined in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If `e` is a reference to a DOM element and you have a class like this: `.t {color:green;}` then you want reference the class name as a string:

```
e.className = 't';
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that works (with the class name as a string, as jonah mentioned). Also, you can set style attributes directly on an object, using the [DOM Level 2 Style](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/) interface. e.g.,

```
button.style.fontFamily = "Verdana, Arial, sans-serif";
```

where `button` is (presumably) a button object. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not only that works, but it's even a best practice.

You definitively want to separate the data format (xHTML) from the design (CSS) and the behaviour (javascript).

So it's far better to just add and remove classes in JS according to event while the esthetic concerns are delegated to css styles.

E.G : Coloring an error message in red.

CSS

```
.error
{
    color: red;
}
```

JS

```
var error=document.getElementById('error');
error.className='error';
```

N.B :

- This snippet is just an example. In real life you would use js just for that.
- document.getElementById is not always interoperable. Better to use a JS framework to handle that. I personally use JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example that add and remove the class using jQuery.

```
// js
  $("p:first").addClass("t");
  $("p:first").removeClass("t");

// css
  .t {
    backgound: red
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('id').className = 't'
```